# What type of paint to recoat a ceramic tile hearth?

Tags: tile, paint, repainting

The hearth in front of my newly retiled fireplace (which was described in a [DIY blog](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2014/02/tiling-a-fireplace-surround/)) needs repainting to complete the job.

The hearth is made up of 6x6 ceramic tiles that have a well adhered coat of paint (or more likely several coats) over both the tiles and the grout. The surface is satin and has only a few small areas that have been worn through. There is no flaking.

I plan to wire brush any loose paint, sand lightly and wipe clean.

**The Question:** What type of paint is best to stand up to the scuffing of shoes, logs and fireplace tools, and to withstand a bit of heat (near the firebox edge) and the possible occasional flying cinder?

Answer (score 2):

I like the hardness of enamels.  Oil based trim paint or the newer water borne oils are quite tough.

Comment: Any benefit to Porch and Deck enamel? Or epoxy? Heat issues with any of them?

Comment: Either should work.  If the existing coat(s) show no sign of charring, you should be good.  I would lean to an epoxy for both heat and wear, but the self cross linking resins in the water borne oils are tough.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a top coat of [Parks Super Glaze](http://www.rustoleum.com/en/product-catalog/consumer-brands/parks/super-glaze) in high traffic areas.  It is shiny but it finishes off really nice and the stuff is really hard after a day or two.  There are other similar products as this but I have not used them recently.

Comment: Will this work on a vertical surface?

Comment: @HerrBag  Yes.  Just takes more time.  Last time I used it, I did an end table and was too lazy to do all four sides separately.